# pandas read a crappy csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I got a poorly written `csv` file that I want to load using pandas'  `read_csv`. Below are the first few lines to illustrate how it looks and the error generated.
File `test.csv`:

```py
feature_idx,cv_scores,avg_score,total-features
(4,),[0.71657    0.75430665 0.77866281 0.85293036 0.76370522],0.773235007449579,80
(4, 15),[0.79150981 0.82751849 0.83777517 0.9246948  0.82462535],0.8412247254527763,80
(1, 4, 15),[0.82173419 0.85052599 0.86065046 0.93704226 0.84315839],0.862622256166522,80
(1, 4, 15, 70),[0.82448556 0.86513518 0.87640778 0.93881338 0.84777784],0.8705239466728865,80
```

When I attempt to load it:

```py
pandas.read_csv('test.csv')

pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 5 fields in line 4, saw 6
```

I understand this is because the first filed is a `tuple`. How do I let `pandas` know the first field is a `tuple` so that everything between `(..)` is regarded as one field?

**EDIT**

The current answer didn't work yet.

```py
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', converters={'feature_idx': parse_tuple}) # parse_tuple as per the answer

pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 5 fields in line 4, saw 6

# pandas version
>>> print(pd.__version__)
1.5.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) with a *regex* separator to ignore enclosed commas `(,)`:

```
from ast import literal_eval

df = pd.read_csv("file.txt", sep=",(?![^(]*[)])", engine="python")

df["feature_idx"] = df["feature_idx"].apply(literal_eval)

df["cv_scores"] = df["cv_scores"].str.strip("[]").str.split()
```

> Regex : [[*demo*](https://regex101.com/r/EK9DvK/1)]

Output :

```
>>> print(df)

      feature_idx                      cv_scores  avg_score  total-features
0            (4,)  [0.71657, 0.75430665, 0.77...   0.773235              80
1         (4, 15)  [0.79150981, 0.82751849, 0...   0.841225              80
2      (1, 4, 15)  [0.82173419, 0.85052599, 0...   0.862622              80
3  (1, 4, 15, 70)  [0.82448556, 0.86513518, 0...   0.870524              80
```

*With the element-types :*

```
feature_idx     <class 'tuple'>
cv_scores        <class 'list'>
avg_score       <class 'float'>
total-features    <class 'int'>
```